# is there a way to list words in the current Red console

Tags: red

Is there an object like rebol/words available in the REPL build with console.red ?

I am using the red-master currently on github ( it says alpha and Latin-1 only but no other version id and I didn't see anything at top of console.red)

I was trying some functions but didn't have a listing of those available ( it may be right under my nose ... )

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use **words-of system/words** to get a list of all words defined in global context.

Use **system/version** to get the version and **system/build/date** for the build date.